# Setting a start and end date for countdown timer? (using Meteor.js)

Tags: javascript, meteor

Right now I have a countdown timer working from the current system time counting down to and endtime, but I want to be able to create a start time as well, and I'm not sure how to do that. Here is my javascript right now:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
var timeinterval;

Meteor.startup(function () {
var starttime = 'February 19 2016 22:00:00 UTC-0600'
var endtime = 'February 21 2016 10:00:00 UTC-0600';
timeinterval = setInterval(function () {
  Meteor.call("getCurrentTime", function (error, result) {
    Session.set("time", result);
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);
    Session.set("t", t);
  });
}, 1000);
});

function getTimeRemaining(endtime){
var t = Date.parse(endtime) - starttime;
var seconds = ("0" + Math.floor( (t/1000) % 60 )).slice(-2);
var minutes = ("0" + Math.floor( (t/1000/60) % 60 )).slice(-2);
var hours = ("0" + Math.floor( (t/(1000*60*60)) % 24 )).slice(-2);
var days = Math.floor( t/(1000*60*60*24) );

console.log(t)
if(t <= 0)
  clearInterval(timeinterval);

return {
  'total': t,
  'days': days,
  'hours': hours,
  'minutes': minutes,
  'seconds': seconds
};

}

Template.countdown.helpers({
t: function () {
  return Session.get("t");
}
});

Template.body.helpers({
ended:function () {
  console.log(Session.get("t").total <= 0);
  return Session.get("t").total <= 0;
}
});
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
 Meteor.startup(function () {

});

Meteor.methods({
 'getCurrentTime': function (){
   return Date.parse(new Date());
 }
 });
 }
```

I'm really not sure where to go from here, as I don't have any experience with javascript. Any help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sounds to me if I understand correctly, you want to either countdown to start (if start is later than now), or countdown to end (if it's already started).

Or maybe you just want to not show the timer unless it's started, not clear from your question.

Either way, just modify your getTimeRemaining function to take in start time parameter as well, and check whether if now is less than start, if so then count against start instead of end.

```js
function getTimeRemaining(starttime, endtime){
  // translate JSdate to Ms before you can compare
  var nowInMs = new Date().getTime();
  var startTimeMs = starttime.getTime();
  
  if (nowInMs < startTimeMs) {
    ... do what you wanted, maybe compare diff and count from there
    ... or just not show the timer
  } else {
    ... do what you were doing
  }
```

Hope that helped :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about creating a 'time since XYZ date' timer, I'd use this package: https://github.com/copleykj/meteor-livestamp

This will provide you with functionality to say how long it's been since something happened (e.g. 3 minutes ago), just like with Facebook comments.

Comment: Actually I'm trying to do sort of opposite of that. I need a timer that starts at a certain time and ends at a certain time. So I need to set start time for Feb 10 and end for Feb 11